# Filtering by an Array of Values, Rather than a Single Value, in my Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, typescript

I have a working search feature in my Angular 2 app, that lets users click on one of several radio buttons in order to filter results based on a particular category. This is working as expected when the relationship between what I'm calling in my view is a one-to-one relationship with the database. Here's what I have for the radio button filters (whatever's listed in "value" corresponds with the database):

```
<form #f="ngForm" class="filters">
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="category" [(ngModel)]="category" (click)="refresh()"> All
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="administration" name="category" [(ngModel)]="category"> Staff
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="contractor" name="category" [(ngModel)]="category"> Contractors
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="client" name="category" [(ngModel)]="category"> Clients
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="doctor" name="category" [(ngModel)]="category"> Doctors
  </div>
</form>
```

Now, of those radio button options, one is proving trickier for me, because it's actually a sub-set of an array of values. So rather than being one value is equal to one value in the database, what I need to do is have the search function filter based on each of the values in that array when that one radio button is clicked. To clarify, in our mongoDB setup, the data for this one section looks like this:

```
department: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true, enum: { values: ["administration", "distribution", "human resources", "information technology", "marketing"], message: "Value of staff must be of one type." } },
```

Now, I can have any ONE of these values in my view code, and it will filter successfully for that category. So, for instance, you'll see above that "administration" is one of the values in this array, and so if I have this in my view, it works:

```
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="administration" name="category" [(ngModel)]="category"> Staff
  </div>
```

But how do I need to set this up so that it will pull results from ALL of the sub-categories? (i.e. from ["administration", "distribution", "human resources", "information technology", "marketing"]?

I tried using a join method in my component, and then binding to that with square brackets in the view, but that didn't work. So what can I do here to handle this one section which is an array of values, rather than a single value?

Comment: Make all your one to one values into arrays of length 1 and display all your results the same way?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just handle the one instance uniquely, rather than making the others more complicated than they need to be? Also, I don't handle the server-side - just the client end.

Comment: And, to clarify, the other values are not arrays of one on the server. It's just this one category that is an array of sub-categories.